# 18.04 cannot Install Ubuntu from menu option, but works from within a Live Session

Tags: 18.04

Trying to install 18.04 from DVD, when I selected **Install Ubuntu** from the menu, the DVD spins, stops with a black screen and then proceeds to boot into a Live session. From within the Live session the Install Ubuntu link on the desktop successfully installs to disk.

This is a new ASUS motherboard. I've disable Secure Boot in the UEFI BIOS. Any idea what causes this behavior?

Comment: Having a similar issue with 18.04.1 on a live USB on older hardware.